# Function or associated item cannot be called upon benchmarking

Tags: parachain, benchmarking

I’m trying to run benchmarks on the latest commit in this PR https://github.com/InvArch/InvArch-Node/pull/87 The pallet library pallet library is separate so the runtime depends on this latest commit in this PR https://github.com/InvArch/InvArch-Frames/pull/152

I am able to compile without errors with cargo `build --release`

But when I run `cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks`, it produce some errors for 2 out of 4 pallets that was being benchmarked, as shown below:

```
error[E0599]: the function or associated item `run_benchmark` exists for struct `pallet_ips::Pallet<Runtime>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
      --> /home/sha888/invarch/InvArch-Node/runtime/src/lib.rs:1079:13
       |
  797  | / construct_runtime!(
  798  | |     pub enum Runtime where
  799  | |         Block = Block,
  800  | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...    |
  841  | |     }
  842  | | );
       | |_- doesn't satisfy `<_ as pallet_ipl::Config>::Licenses = pallet_ips::benchmarking::InvArchLicenses`
  ...
  1079 |               add_benchmark!(params, batches, pallet_ips, Ips);
       |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on `pallet_ips::Pallet<Runtime>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
       |
      ::: /home/sha888/.cargo/git/checkouts/invarch-frames-d642bcfed68b46a3/c3c9d40/INV4/pallet-ips/src/lib.rs:125:5
       |
  125  |       pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
       |       ------------------------ doesn't satisfy `pallet_ips::Pallet<Runtime>: Benchmarking`
       |
       = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
               `<Runtime as pallet_ipl::Config>::Licenses = pallet_ips::benchmarking::InvArchLicenses`
               which is required by `pallet_ips::Pallet<Runtime>: Benchmarking`
       = note: this error originates in the macro `add_benchmark` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0599]: the function or associated item `run_benchmark` exists for struct `pallet_ipt::Pallet<Runtime>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
      --> /home/sha888/invarch/InvArch-Node/runtime/src/lib.rs:1080:13
       |
  797  | / construct_runtime!(
  798  | |     pub enum Runtime where
  799  | |         Block = Block,
  800  | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...    |
  841  | |     }
  842  | | );
       | |_- doesn't satisfy `<_ as pallet_ipt::Config>::Call = pallet_ipt::Call<Runtime>`
  ...
  1080 |               add_benchmark!(params, batches, pallet_ipt, Ipt);
       |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on `pallet_ipt::Pallet<Runtime>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
       |
      ::: /home/sha888/.cargo/git/checkouts/invarch-frames-d642bcfed68b46a3/c3c9d40/INV4/pallet-ipt/src/lib.rs:121:5
       |
  121  |       pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
       |       ------------------------ doesn't satisfy `pallet_ipt::Pallet<Runtime>: Benchmarking`
       |
       = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
               `<Runtime as pallet_ipt::Config>::Call = pallet_ipt::Call<Runtime>`
               which is required by `pallet_ipt::Pallet<Runtime>: Benchmarking`
       = note: this error originates in the macro `add_benchmark` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: The compiler seems to be telling you the problem: `doesn't satisfy <_ as pallet_ipl::Config>::Licenses = pallet_ips::benchmarking::InvArchLicenses`

Comment: it seems they are originating from the `where_clause` in `benchmarking.rs` of ips and ipt pallets.

Comment: Thank you!. We'll try to iterate it over.